# join on indexed fields doesn't utilize indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables. I've written a query to JOIN them on one column. This column is indexed in both tables, but MySQL is not using the indexes. Can someone a) tell me why and b) tell me how I might get MySQL use an index to join these tables quickly.

First table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `dol_msa_zip_assoc` (
  `pkey` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zip` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pmsa_msa` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkey`),
  KEY `zip` (`zip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It contains 42690 records.

The other table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `v3_msa_zip_assoc` (
  `pkey` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zip` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pmsa_msa` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkey`),
  KEY `zip` (`zip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

it contains 42486 records.

My query, intended to find records in the first table not in the second:

```sql
SELECT d.*, o.* FROM `dol_msa_zip_assoc` d
LEFT JOIN `v3_msa_zip_assoc` o
ON o.zip = d.zip
WHERE o.zip IS NULL
```

When I EXPLAIN this query, I see that the indexes on the **zip** column are not being used:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                                          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 42915 | NULL                                                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 42486 | Using where; Not exists; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What might be causing this failure to use the indexes? Is it because one zip column is latin1 and the other utf8? How can I get this query to utilize the indexes so it doesn't take an age to run?

EDIT: reversing the order of the JOIN apparently does make use of the index:

```sql
SELECT d . * , o . *
FROM `v3_msa_zip_assoc` o
LEFT JOIN `dol_msa_zip_assoc` d ON d.zip = o.zip
WHERE d.zip IS NULL
```

Here's the explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                   |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 42486 | NULL                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ref  | zip           | zip  | 17      | func |     1 | Using where; Not exists |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------------------+
```

EDIT 2: I have changed the structure of the old table to use utf8 collations. It is now defined thusly:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `v3_msa_zip_assoc` (
  `pkey` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zip` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pmsa_msa` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkey`),
  KEY `zip` (`zip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This appears to have remedied the problem:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT d . * , o . *
    -> FROM `dol_msa_zip_assoc` d
    -> LEFT JOIN `v3_msa_zip_assoc` o ON o.zip = d.zip
    -> WHERE o.zip IS NULL;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+-------+-------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref                 | rows  | Extra                   |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+-------+-------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL                | 42915 | NULL                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ref  | zip           | zip  | 29      | myplan_v4_dev.d.zip |     1 | Using where; Not exists |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+-------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Well, `varchar(5)` and `varchar(9)` are not the same type, so this might preclude the use of indexes for the join.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried reversing the JOIN (see edit to OP) and the indexes is used. And why shouldn't an index be used if they are both varchar fields?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: it's the characterset

Comment: on EDIT 2, the join predicate has changed to reference `pmsa_msa` column, rather than `zip` column, so we wouldn't expect an index on zip column to be used for the join. .

Comment: @spencer7593 ah yes you are correct. I will re-edit to clarify. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the characterset that's preventing the use of the index.

One of the zip columns is latin1, the other is utf8.

There's an implicit conversion,  equivalent to `CONVERT(zip USING charset)` on one side,

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you have any documentation or something that might explain this behavior morefully?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html   excerpt  "For comparisons between nonbinary string columns, both columns should use the same character set. For example, comparing a utf8 column with a latin1 column precludes use of an index."

Comment: Thanks so much for that reference. However, I redefined the second table (see my OP which I have edited) and the EXPLAIN of my query still says that the zip indices will not be used. Puzzling.

Comment: on EDIT 2 of the question, the join predicate references column `pmsa_msa` and not `zip` column, so we would not expect EXPLAIN to show the index on the `zip` column being used.